# Nonlinear transformation using the beta distribution

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-regression, beta-distribution

I'm trying to estimate the following equation (abstracted from [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/jofi.12151) paper) in Matlab:

$y_i=a+b\frac{(x_i-min(x))^{(c-1)}(max(x)-x_i)^{d-1}}{B(c,d)(max(x)-min(x))^{c+d-1}}+\epsilon_i$

where $B(c,d)$ is the beta function. The parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are estimated using a least squares fit.

The beta function is defined for $c,d>0$, so I think this should be the lower bound for these parameters. What I don't understand is when $x_i$ takes the value $min(x)$. The term $x_i-min(x)$ becomes zero and its power becomes negative for $0<c<1$. The term  $(x_i-min(x))^{c-1}$ is then undefined and Matlab can't estimate the equation (for code see below). Same goes for the term $(max(x)-x_i)^{d-1}$. What am I missing here?

---

Code (using the Curve Fitting Tool and Custom Equation):

```
y = f(x) = a+b*(x-min(x))^(c-1)*(max(x)-x)^(d-1)/(beta(c,d)*(max(x)-min(x))^(c+d-1))
```

Comment: This is a fishy model.  It appears to use $\min(x)$ and $\max(x)$ as *estimators* of the range of the scaled and shifted Beta density.  This would be reasonably accurate only for small values of $c$ and $d$ and huge datasets.  The potential infinities, however, force $c \ge 1$ and $d \ge 1$.  That doesn't seem to leave much room to estimate $c$ and $d$!  Unfortunately the paper is behind a paywall and its abstract reveals nothing about this model or the assumptions behind it.

Comment: A version of this paper from a conference three years earlier than the publication date is [here](https://fisher.osu.edu/blogs/efa2011/files/CFE_10_3.pdf). The equation is equation 16 (p22) of that pdf.

Comment: @whuber Actually in one of the estimations the restriction $c\leq 1$ is used. So I guess somehow my interpretation of how to estimate the model must be wrong. Could it not just be that $min(x)$ and $max(x)$ are dropped from the data when estimating? This would solve the 'potential infinities' but doesn’t seem like a proper solution to me. (By the way I would like to suggest using [this](http://blog.iese.edu/financeseminars/files/2012/10/Eckbo.pdf) version instead as it resembles the final version a little bit more (see equation 14 on page 16).)